# Icon inside the leaflet control layer does not display

Tags: leaflet

I created a leaflet control layer to switch between two base maps (Bing and OpenCycleMap), Yet I don't see the icon inside the layer control:

```
var baseMaps = {
             "Bing": bingLayer,
              "OpenCycleMap": tileLayer
         };
        L.control.layers(baseMaps).addTo(map);
```

The result in the navigator:

[image]

The way I call my leaflet :

```
echo $this->Html->css('leaflet');
echo $this->Html->script('leaflet');
```

Is there any special config to add the layer icon instead of the blank space? As I know this icon should be by default displayed.

Your help would be grateful.

Comment: Since your button looks correctly styled except for the icon, it means you correctly imported Leaflet CSS but are probably missing the associated images. If you need further help, make sure to describe how you import library files and your project files structure.

Comment: What about your project file structure? Do you have the images alongside your CSS file?